# Is there is a way to replace multiple character with replace function?

Tags: javascript

my replace function only replace one character.

**My Code example**

```
const string = "What,Yo,Yes"
string.replace(","," ")
```

**Console**

"What Yo,Yes"

Comment: you can use regex with "/g"

Comment: please using answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
const string = "What,Yo,Yes";
console.log(string.replace(/,/g," "));
```

Alternatively, you can use replaceAll, like this:

```
const string = "What,Yo,Yes"; 
console.log(string.replaceAll(","," "));
```